# Canceling a Limit with 'Inverse Limit'

Tags: calculus, limits, inverse

Is there an operator that cancels a limit (inverse limit)? For example $lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{x}$: Can one take an 'inverse limit' to cancel with this limit and output $e^{x}$? Let A='inverse limit', then A( $lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{x})=e^{x}$

Best Regards,
Thank You

Comment: @VectorCalculus I've never heard of one. May I ask why you are interested in such a property?

Comment: I was curious and I was also trying to simplify and integral using this, however I do not think this exists. @user166967 Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an operation may not exist, as a limit is not a bijective "mapping"

Just as binary multiplication takes $$ \cdot \,\,  : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$, 
as in $2 \cdot 3 = 6$, we may not recover this information through any sort of inverse operation, bijectively. That is, given the number $6$, I cannot construct

$$A: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$$  for this is **clearly** not bijective. $A(6) = 2 \cdot 3, 6 \cdot 1, 5 \cdot \frac{6}{5}$, etc. The same sort of issue exists when trying to take an inverse limit operation.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^n = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n \in N} x^n = \, \, \text{etc} \,\, = \infty$$

Comment: Okay thank you, I see why this wouldn't be a valid operation.@AnthonyPeter

Answer (score 1):

For any given limit value $L$, there are uncountably many functions such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$.

To see this, pick any one function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$, and define a new function $\bar{f}$ such that $\bar{f}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ except $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ (a finite set of points). You can define $\bar{f}(x_1), \ldots, \bar{f}(x_n)$ arbitrarily. Then, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to c}\bar{f}(x) = L$. Of course, there are more functions whose limit as $x \to c$ is $L$.

Sticking to "nice" functions, you can still come up with examples of functions with the same limit. For example, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}e^x = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}(x^2+1) = \lim_{x \to 0}1 = 1$.

Thus, if you are given the value of a limit, you cannot uniquely determine what the function was. Hence, there is no "inverse limit" operation.

Comment: Thank you!! I understand now..However, has anyone ever though of taking inverse operations on operators of functions that are not bijective?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 There is an [inverse limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit). Do you know if it is related to the question?